# Matlab code convert into Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have been coding in Matlab for many years, and was recently suggested Python by many people as a future. Being interested I started learning it. I do not want to compare these two and currently am in a learning phase for Python. Since I have a lot of codes written in Matlab (and more importantly talk in Matlab), I thought there would be an equivalent command for 'almost' all commands in Matlab. We use the

```
k = 1:n;
```

a lot in Matlab. But in Python I simply struggle to get this simple thing work. I tried using arange, but never really realized what the error is:

```
>>> arange(1,]10[,1,])
File "<stdin>", line 1
arange(1,]10[,1,])
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> arange(1,10[,1,])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    arange(1,10[,1,])
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> arange([1,]10[,1,])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    arange([1,]10[,1,])
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> np.arange
<built-in function arange>
>>> arange([1], 10[,1])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    arange([1], 10[,1])
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I went to the [numpy website](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and tried to give the syntax there, but again:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange([1],10[,1],dtype=None)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    np.arange([1],10[,1],dtype=None)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I wouldn't have written this post just to clarify something of this sort, but my point is why is this simplest Matlab command so very complicated in Python? I even used [this tool](https://github.com/victorlei/smop) to convert .m codes to .py codes, with little effect.

Comment: `[]` in documentation usually means that something is *optional*. `np.arange` has a few optional arguments. The square brackets aren't actual Python syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the non-matching square braces in your function call. In documentation, the square braces only indicate that something is optional, they are not included in the call. Also note that this functionality is native to python in the range command and you would not need to use numpy.

Matlab:

```
n=5;
k=1:n
```

Python:

```
n=5
k=range(1,n+1)
```

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
n=5
k=np.arange(1,n+1)
```

I would suggest installing ipython. As someone who has also migrated from matlab to python this is an essential tool to understanding syntax without the frustration of running a script repeatedly. http://ipython.org/

Answer (score 0):

`k = 1:n;` is equivalent

```
k = range(1, n+1)
```

or

```
k = np.arange(1, n+1)
```

Note that the index of Python is started at `0` not `1`. If you use `k` for indexing of array you should use

```
k = np.range(n) # which is [0, 1, ..., n-1]
```

This [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) may help Matlab users.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this in numpy.  This simplest is this:

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
k = np.r_[1:n+1]
```

Another approach would be to start with 0 and add 1, but this is a tiny bit slower (it was about 1.5 ms slower for n=1000000 on my system):

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
k = np.r_[:n]+1
```

Note that if you start with 0, you can leave off the initial zero.

You can do something similar with arange:

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
k = np.arange(n)+1
```